# no template argument specified but still works

Tags: c++, templates, stl

This is the function declaration of STL `make_heap` which expects the random-access iterators as the arguments

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
    void make_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
```

But when we call it :

```
 std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
```

We dont specify the `template argument` . why so...?

Does C++ automaticaly detect which data type we are passing in the fucntion call...?

Is this `implicit type-casting` ...?

Comment: [_Template argument deduction_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Comment: Lookup [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). (Or just click it :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of determining template arguments based on function arguments is called template argument deduction.

From the C++ Standard

14.8.2 Template argument deduction

> 1 When a function template specialization is referenced, all of the
>   template arguments shall have values. The values can be explicitly
>   specified or, in some cases, be deduced from the use or obtained from
>   default template-arguments.

[ Example:

```
void f(Array<dcomplex>& cv, Array<int>& ci) {
sort(cv); // calls sort(Array<dcomplex>&)
sort(ci); // calls sort(Array<int>&)
}
```